# Serve express dynamic URL using NGINX with Nodejs reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, angular, express, nginx

I am using Express for serving static files and dynamic URLs on my nodejs app. I am generating a URL based on the :id in Mongodb and then on NGINX I am using Nodejs reverse proxy to serve this path to the user but it doesn't work whatever I try. It always says "CANNOT GET.."

I am running NGINX 1.14.2, Node 8.14.0. I have tried NGINX rewrite directive and various wild cards ( ~*, ~^, .*, etc.) but none of them have worked. I have included the current express code and NGINX config below. Any help is hugely appreciated

Express

```
    router.get('/dynamic-uri/:fooId', function (req, res) {
         res.render('index');
    });
```

The resultant URL with :fooId is

```
   https://example.com/myNodeApp/dynamic-uri/5c35e51228122504b57126d7
```

NGINX Config

```
location /myNodeApp/dynamic-uri {
    proxy_pass http://x.x.x.x:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

Of course the :fooId doesn't exist as a static path and to serve static files i have the following block which works fine

```
location ~* /myNodeApp/(static|img|media|app|css|js) {
    proxy_pass http://x.x.x.x:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

Comment: try to change `location /myNodeApp/dynamic-uri` to `location /myNodeApp/` and test again

Comment: and `proxy_pass http://x.x.x.x:3000;` should be `proxy_pass http://x.x.x.x:3000/;`

Comment: @Thanh Nguyen Van I've tried both already and neither of them worked

Comment: whats error code ?

Comment: Cannot GET is error

Comment: application error code and nginx error code ?

Comment: Application error

Comment: Can you show the code where you mount the router to the app? It should look like`app.use('/myNodeApp', router)`

Comment: I am using jade so I join the path this way

        app.use(`${staticPath}/views`, jadeStatic(path.join('./app-frontend/views/')));

And I get the staticPath from config where it is set to /myNodeApp

Comment: can you access http://x.x.x.x:3000/myNodeApp/dynamic-uri/5c35e51228122504b57126d7 ?

Comment: No.

x.x.x.x:3000/myNodeApp/dynamic-uri/5c35e51228122504b57126d7 returns Cannot GET /dynamic-uri/5c35e51228122504b57126d7

Comment: so, nodejs app hasnot worked yet.

Comment: Nope, not yet it hasn't worked